# What does tar's -p (preserve permissions) flag actually preserve?

Tags: command-line, permissions, tar

What does the `-p` flag actually preserve when creating and extracting a tarball?
Is it the `rwx` permissions it preserves?

When I created a `htdocs/` tarball owned by root, extracting it to my local machine changed the ownership from root to my user.

Comment: Maybe you should try to extract the archive as root. It's not possible to set permissions for another user as a normal user so I think `tar` won't be able to do so as well. Please tell me if this worked.

Comment: "local machine"? Please clarify what OS this machine has ;)

Comment: Also tell us what filesystems you are using. Both the source and target ones.

Comment: Source: `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)`  
Target: `Ubuntu 13.10`  
Both use `GPT`

Comment: Side note: `tar` preserves permissions. `-p` and `--same-owner` / `--no-same-owner` (as in answers) are extraction flags. They have no effect while archiving

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ownership and permissions are two different things. The `-p` flag preserves *permissions*. On *nix systems, regular users can't change file ownership to a user who is not themselves.

As explained [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chown.html) :

> Only processes with an effective user ID equal to the user ID of the file or with appropriate privileges may change the ownership of a file. If _POSIX_CHOWN_RESTRICTED is in effect for path:
>
> - Changing the user ID is restricted to processes with appropriate privileges.
> - Changing the group ID is permitted to a process with an effective user ID equal to the user ID of the file, but without appropriate privileges, if and only if owner is equal to the file's user ID or ( uid_t)-1 and group is equal either to the calling process' effective group ID or to one of its supplementary group IDs.

The rationale behind this has been nicely explained by @Gilles in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27374/22222) Unix & Linux answer:

> The reason for this restriction is that giving away a file to another
>   user can allow bad things to happen in uncommon, but still important
>   situations. For example:
>
> - If a system has disk quotas enabled, Alice could create a world-writable file under a directory accessible only by her (so no
>     one else could access that world-writable directory), and then run
>     chown to make that file owned by another user Bill. The file would
>     then count under Bill's disk quota even though only Alice can use the
>     file.
> - If Alice gives away a file to Bill, there is no trace that Bill didn't create that file. This can be a problem if the file contains
>     illegal or otherwise compromising data.
> - Some programs require that their input file belongs to a particular user in order to authenticate a request (for example, the
>     file contains some instructions that the program will perform on
>     behalf of that user). This is usually not a secure design, because
>     even if Bill created a file containing syntactically correct
>     instructions, he might not have intended to execute them at this
>     particular time. Nonetheless, allowing Alice to create a file with
>     arbitrary content and have it taken as input from Bill can only make
>     things worse.

So, even if you use tar's `--same-owner` flag, you will still need to extract the files as `root` to preserve ownership. That flag is on by default for `root`, so what you want is:

```
sudo tar xpf foo.tgz
```

Answer (score 12):

There are 2 more options for tar that are interesting:

```
--same-owner
       try extracting files with the same ownership as exists in the ar‐
       chive (default for superuser)

--no-same-owner
       extract files as yourself (**default for ordinary users**)
```

The 2nd one is the default so you can add `--same-owner` to save your user. You probably will have to do this with `sudo`.

Besides that: this will -only- work on systems that support POSIX. And operating systems other than Ubuntu might not have these 2 options (they are not standard).

Comment: The `--same-owner` won't work for non-root users, they won't have the right to set the ownership to anyone but themselves. That's defined by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chown.html).

Answer (score 4):

To preserve owner run as root or use the --same-owner flag alongside the -p flag when extracting.

Comment: It needs to be run as root in any case. Non-root users can't change file ownership to other users.